# Appmaker - How to open a particular record in a form using URL?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-app-maker

I have a table naming Employee in Appmaker. Lets say it contains 3 records.

```
empId empName empAge

1      Abc    29

2      Def    26

3      Xyz   30
```

I have 2 forms :-

```
AddEmployee - It has datasource Employee(create) to create new Employee

EditEmployee - It has datasource Employee to edit Employee records.
```

I have set the onClick function of the Employee table row to open the record in the EditEmployee form and it works fine. (POST method is used by default)

However I want to use GET method.
Requirement is to send the URL of a particular record in email to someone such that when the person clicks on the URL that record opens up in the EditEmployee form.

I tried the below expecting the 2nd record to open but it always opens the tables's first record in the form irrespective of the requestId value.

**app.datasources.AppSettings.item.AppUrl+'?requestId=2#EditEmployee';**

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use [google.script.url](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/url) api. The best thing to do is to include some script in the **onDataLoad** event of the table. Take the following for example:

```
  google.script.url.getLocation(function(location){
    var rId = location.parameter.requestId;
    var hash = location.hash;
    if(rId && hash === "EditEmployee"){
      var ds = app.datasources.Employee;
      ds.selectKey(rId);
    }
  });
```

The above assumes that the hash #EditEmployee refers to a page named **EditEmployee**, because if it is a page fragment, the approach changes a bit. Nevertheless, this should give you an idea. Of course, your question is missing required info to help me give you a complete answer so this is the best I can do now.

Comment: Thanks, I did few changes in your function and placed it in onDataLoad event of EditEmployee form. It worked.